# InputStream return null

Tags: java, ftp

I´m trying to download files via ftp, but retrieveFileStream return null, I have checked getReplyString and return 200, this is my code:

```
File file = new File(this.config.getDestDirectory() + File.separator + fileName);
String t = this.ftp.getReplyString();
InputStream in = this.ftp.retrieveFileStream(fileName);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
StreamUtils.copy(in, fos);
in.close();
fos.close();
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Your InputStream looks at `fileName`, not at `file`. Is this intended?

Comment: What's "ftp" and where did it come from?

Comment: Thanks for answer, Yes, is intended, according the API the param of the retrieveFileStream is the name of the remote file and in my code file is directory of out: FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

Comment: ftp is FTPClient and also I have checked ftp.isconected and return true.

Comment: I suppose you are using the [Apache Commons FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) ?

Comment: Thanks for all, already solved, retrieveFileStream need full path: url ftp + filename.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.. Its an example from my code base, i have used the open source Apache commons-net-ftp-2.0.

```
public void goforIt()
{
    FTPClient con = null;

    try
    {
        con = new FTPClient();
        con.connect("10.0.0.1");     // Dummy address

        if (con.login("Administrator", "KUjWbk361wobbyl"))
        {
            con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
            con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            String data = "/sdcard/2prerakm4a.m4a";

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(data));
            boolean result = con.retrieveFile("prerakm4a.m4a", out);
            out.close();
            if (result) Log.v("download result", "succeeded");
            con.logout();
            con.disconnect();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.v("download result","failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK. You are suppose to finalize file transfers by calling completePendingCommand() and verifying that the transfer was indeed successful. i.e. you need to add call the function below fos.clos().

fos.close();
client.completePendingCommand()

that should do!
You may also consider this, according to the API for FTPClient.retrieveFileStream(), the method returns null when it cannot open the data connection, in which case you should check the reply code (e.g. getReplyCode(), getReplyString(), getReplyStrings()) to see why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you have already verified all above mentioned answer and still having issue, just check above settings under source. If you have Excluded:** then none of the file will be available, if you just remove that ** from Edit option your code should work. I have

Answer (score -1):

Here you can see when this method returns null:
http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/src-html/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#line.1742

Comment: downvoting because it's a link only answer and the link is dead now. X(

Comment: As I could find from the sources, "null is returned if an FTP protocol error is reported at any point during the establishment and initialization of the connection". See org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient#_openDataConnection_(String, String)